# Multiple Terminal to select a number from a list

Tags: mysql, winforms, c#-2.0

I am using c# winforms-MySql Server.

I have 12 values and in every hour I need to select one value from that 12 value list. Timer can easily select the number.

But the problem is I have 5 Terminal where the software is to be installed.
They all will select a value from the list. The value can be same or different.
But **I need the select same value for all the terminal**. I don't have any client-server facility because any terminal can be open or closed at any time.

Can MySql select a value from a list in every hour without any c# code?
Any concept will be helpful. I don't need any code if you have a problem.
Thanks

Comment: Do you choose the value randomly? Or it follows some rule?

Comment: I am following some rule to remove some elements and then randomly select from the rest of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be:

- Create a Table with only 1 Column and 1 Row. It will contain, in the single cell, the current synchronized value;
- Create a Timer in mySql. You can get some useful infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018992/how-to-set-a-timer-in-mysql);
- The Timer makes a Stored Procedure to run;
- That Stored Procedure updates the synchronized value;
- All the Terminals query the database looking for that value, whenever and however you want: they will always retrieve the a synchronized value.

Comment: ts a perfect solution for the question I asked. But I need to start the event every day at 9:00 Am and stops at 9:56 PM. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Sourav the link I posted contains some answers that talk exactly about scheduling a database event at a certain date and time.

Comment: @Sourav check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)