# how to set a timer in mysql and update a field after timer set to 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am working with net banking project when a customer entered wrong password 3 times in succession,I want account to be locked for 2hrs
How to implement this with mysql?

Comment: I already apply functionality of locking the account when someone entered wrong password but i don't know about how to handle timer in mysql so can u tell me ? 
That's what i wanted to know.(answer to your comment)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you look for the answer before posting your question?

The following answer is helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019922/793934

Its summary is that you can use `MySql` events. Of course, you can manage the situation manually and independent from the database. You have to store the time on incorrect password and after that compare the current time with the stored time.

Answer (score 1):

Store the time of wrongly entered password and check the time difference when accessing the account