# Reset value in database after 'x' amount of time

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a competition page and have a ticket table in mysql. Each ticket contains an availability column which is either '1' or '0' (true or false).

When the user adds a ticket to their basket I am setting the value to 0 so that other users cant attempt to buy that ticket while it is being purchased by someone else. I am wanting a timeout so that the value will essentially set back to 1 after x amount of time (let's say 10 minutes)

I get how to do all aspects except this timer. I have seen something about events but I am not sure how to use them.

Pseudocode for what I want

```
adding to basket
availability = 0

trigger timer event
after 10 mins

if purchased = 0
    availability = 1
```

(I am mainly controlling the site with PHP)

Comment: just a note, phpMyAdmin is your mySQL administration tool, no need to tag your question with it, in the end it isn't relevant when the community wants to provide you with answers :)

Comment: There is [How to set a timer in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018992/how-to-set-a-timer-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find life easier if rethink your strategy. You will find that if you change your `availability` field to be a date you can change your strategy to this, and get the same net behaviour without the added complexity of the scheduled process to unlock;

- Allow adding to basket if `availability` before `now` and not purchased.
- Set `availability` to a date in the future that the ticket becomes available to purchase and `purchased` = `0`.
- When someone adds the ticket to their basket set the `availability` field to `now + 10 mins` (this will ensure that for the next 10 mins that ticket cannot be claimed but after 10 mins it will automatically be available without any extra processing).

Comment: Wow I never thought of it like that. I might still have a play around with the timers for something else in my own time but this will definitely be my chosen method. My first question on stack overflow as well so I really appreciate this answer :)